# Avoiding unchecked casts with generics with double extending classes?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, unchecked-cast

I have the following code, which I just refactored to this today since I understand what `<T extends Buffer>` truly means, here is the simplified version:

```
public class Buffer {
    protected final int bufferType;
    protected final int bufferDataType;

    protected int bufferId;
    protected boolean created;

    public Buffer(final int bufferType, final int bufferDataType) {
        this.bufferType = bufferType;
        this.bufferDataType = bufferDataType;
    }

    public <T extends Buffer> T create() {
        assertNotCreated();
        bufferId = GL15.glGenBuffers();

        created = true;
        return (T)this;
    }

    public boolean hasBeenCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    private void assertNotCreated() {
        if (hasBeenCreated()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Buffer has been created already.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ArrayBuffer extends Buffer {
    public ArrayBuffer(final int bufferDataType) {
        super(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferDataType);
    }    
}
```

---

```
public class DynamicDrawArrayBuffer extends ArrayBuffer {
    public DynamicDrawArrayBuffer() {
        super(GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }
}
```

The warning happens at `Buffer.create()`, is it safe to suppress the warning? Is there any way to make it more safe?

The other requirement is that no clutter should be added to the **calling/using** code of this API, concretely this means that `DynamicDrawArrayBuffer` may not get generics attached to it.

Comment: I think this is an abuse of generics. Your create method should be `abstract` and return a `Buffer`. Due to return type covariance then overriding methods can return their own types.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I had this before, but it really looks ugly and is quite annoying to make in my opinion.

Comment: Nonetheless this isn't the correct approach and isn't what generics are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obviously not type-safe. You can write

```
ArrayBuffer a = new ArrayBuffer(0);
DynamicDrawArrayBuffer d = a.create();
```

and this will cause a `ClassCastException`. The return type of the `create` method is inferred from the call site. And the only information that is available at the call site here is that the return value must be a `DynamicDrawArrayBuffer` - so the `ArrayBuffer` is brutally casted to be one.

I think you could easily exploit covariance here: The `create` method could always return the type of the class. The return type of the `create` method then is determined by the type information that you have when you *call* the method:

```
public class BufferTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayBuffer a = new ArrayBuffer();
        ArrayBuffer aa = a.create(); // Yes
        // DynamicDrawArrayBuffer ad = a.create(); // No

        DynamicDrawArrayBuffer d = new DynamicDrawArrayBuffer();
        ArrayBuffer da = a.create(); // Yes
        DynamicDrawArrayBuffer dd = d.create(); // Yes

        Buffer b = a;
        Buffer bb = b.create(); // Yes
        //ArrayBuffer ba = b.create(); // No
    }
}

class Buffer 
{
    public Buffer create() 
    {
        // create etc...
        return this;
    }

}

class DynamicDrawArrayBuffer extends ArrayBuffer 
{
    @Override
    public DynamicDrawArrayBuffer create()
    {
        super.create();
        return this;
    }
}

class ArrayBuffer extends Buffer 
{
    @Override
    public ArrayBuffer create()
    {
        super.create();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even more simplified version:

```
public class Buffer {
    public <T extends Buffer> T create() {
        return (T)this;
    }

    public static class FooBuffer extends Buffer {}
    public static class BarBuffer extends FooBuffer {}

    public static void main(String... args) {
        BarBuffer b = new FooBuffer().create();
    }
}
```

The `main` method compiles without warnings, running the code results in `ClassCastException`. The warning in `create` points to real lack of typesafety in the code.